# how to get different patterns for java.util.Date and java.sql.Timestamp in converted json using faster.xml

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

hi i am using fasterxml 2.6.1 to converter java to json , where as java class is generated using xsds , as shown below

javaclass

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2016-01

```
23T03:04:56+05:30", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.11")
```

public class TestBean {

```
@XmlElement(type = String.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2016-01-23T03:04:56+05:30", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.11")
private Date date ;

@XmlElement(type = String.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2016-01-23T03:04:56+05:30", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.11")
private Timestamp timestamp;

 @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2016-01-23T03:04:56+05:30", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.11")
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

 @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2016-01-23T03:04:56+05:30", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.11")
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

 @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2016-01-23T03:04:56+05:30", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.11")
public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

 @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2016-01-23T03:04:56+05:30", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.11")
public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
}
```

if i convert java to json  By default i will get as time , so i'm setting date format to "YYYYY-MM-DD".

```
public class TestJson {

public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException, ParseException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Date date = new Date();

    TestBean testBean = new TestBean();
    testBean.setDate(date);
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    testBean.setTimestamp(timestamp);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
    mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);

      System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(testBean));

}
```

But i want to get different pattern for Date as well as Timestamp
      Ex . for Date YYYY-MM-DD(2016-01-25)
           for Timestamp dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS 
is there any configuration available in faster xml to get different patterns ??